# How to add http response headers in asp.net 5.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-5

My web application which build on .NET 5.0.
How can I add below http response headers?

```
X-Frame-Options     

Content-Security-Policy  

X-XSS-Protection 

X-Content-Type-Options
```

Above http response headers are missing from web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the easiest approach is in the Startup.cs file:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Header-Name", "Header-Value");
        await next();
    });
```

Make sure you add this call before before calling `UseEndpoints`, `UseMvc` etc.

If you prefer to add these in the web.config, it can be achieved by

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Header-Name" value="Header-Value" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yeah as per your answer i added headers but Content-Security-Policy values affecting my html content . What are the values for Content-Security-Policy header that won't be affecting my html and css content

Comment: How is the html content affected? This might be useful - https://blog.elmah.io/content-security-policy-in-asp-net-mvc/